# Accessing the contents of a callable iterator object

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do some regular expression matching inside a file that contains arabic text of multiple paragraphs, but I cant access the contents of the matching object, my code looks like this :

```
import re 
import pandas as pd

reg =r"^[\u0621-\u064A۰-۹0-9 ]+$"

dataset =pd.read_csv('test.txt',header=None,index_col=False)
for row in dataset.itertuples():
    for pattern in enumerate(row,start=1):
        pattern=row[1].split('\n')
        print(pattern)
        matches=re.finditer(reg,pattern,re.MULTILINE)
        print(matches)
```

I'm using the spyder editor that is embedded in Anaconda distribution for python 3.6.

I have tried the `re.match` function, `lambda x: x[1]` trying to capture the contents, `matches.group()` to iterate over the match segments, `str(pattern)`, and many other solutions but none of them worked as expected.

At some point I managed to see if it finds a match in the first place and it gave me **None** although I checked that my file starts with arabic letters !!

on the other hand I can easily do the task when a simple text is directly passed to the finditer as a string!!

```
import re 
import pandas as pd

reg =r"^[\u0621-\u064A۰-۹0-9 ]+$"

test= ("هو الذي يصوركم في الأرحام كيف يشاء لا إله إلا هو العزيز الحكيم \n"
        "ربنا إنك جامع الناس ليوم لا ريب فيه إن الله لا يخلف الميعاد \n"
       "الصابرين والصادقين والقانتين والمنفقين والمستغفرين بالأسحار \n"
      "0123456789 \n")

#Specifying encoding and text behavior
match=re.finditer(reg,test, re.MULTILINE)
print (match)

#looping over lines inside text
for matchNum, match in enumerate(match, start=1):
    print("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

and the output is just fine as expected :

```
runfile('C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1/Arabic NLP.py', wdir='C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1')
<callable_iterator object at 0x000000000B285BA8>
Match 1 was found at 0-63: هو الذي يصوركم في الأرحام كيف يشاء لا إله إلا هو العزيز الحكيم 
Match 2 was found at 64-124: ربنا إنك جامع الناس ليوم لا ريب فيه إن الله لا يخلف الميعاد 
Match 3 was found at 125-185: الصابرين والصادقين والقانتين والمنفقين والمستغفرين بالأسحار 
Match 4 was found at 186-197: 0123456789
```

the output of the first code must be the match found in the test file it could be something like: 
`['العربية لغة رسمية في كل دول الوطن العربي إضافة إلى كونها لغة رسمية في تشاد وإريتريا وإسرائيل. وهي إحدى اللغات الرسمية الست في منظمة الأمم المتحدة، ويُحتفل باليوم العالمي للغة العربية في 18 ديسمبر كذكرى اعتماد العربية بين لغات العمل في الأمم المتحدة.[7]']`

but it gives me this error and does not proceed to other paragraphs:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1/1-4-2019.py', wdir='C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1')
['اللُّغَة العَرَبِيّة هي أكثر اللغات تحدثاً ونطقاً ضمن مجموعة اللغات السامية، وإحدى أكثر اللغات انتشاراً في العالم، يتحدثها أكثر من 467 مليون نسمة،[4](1) ويتوزع متحدثوها في الوطن العربي، بالإضافة إلى العديد من المناطق الأخرى المجاورة كالأحواز وتركيا وتشاد ومالي والسنغال وإرتيريا وإثيوبيا وجنوب السودان وإيران. اللغة العربية ذات أهمية قصوى لدى المسلمين، فهي عندهم لغة مقدسة إذ أنها لغة القرآن، وهي لغة الصلاة وأساسية في القيام بالعديد من العبادات والشعائر الإسلامية.[5][6]']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-41-3249da970121>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1/1-4-2019.py', wdir='C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1')

  File "C:\Users\Al-Hammad\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 692, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Al-Hammad\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Al-Hammad/Documents/PhD/Second Year 2018-2019/Spring Semester 2018-2019/NLP/Assignments/Assignment 1/1-4-2019.py", line 21, in <module>
    matches=re.finditer(reg,pattern,re.MULTILINE)

  File "C:\Users\Al-Hammad\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\re.py", line 229, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

***Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?***

Comment: Why would you use `pandas` to read a simple text file? Also the nested `for` loops don't really make sense. But back to the issue you're referring to: `pattern=row[1].split('\n')` is going to give you a tuple which you then pass to `re.finditer` however, as the error mentions, it expects a string or bytes-like object (you probably meant to do `pattern=row[1].strip('\n')` instead).

Comment: I used pandas becuase I had some issues with encoding, pandas makes it easy to overcome that. I tried the fix you suggested and it gives me this result: ```العربية لغة رسمية في كل دول الوطن العربي إضافة إلى كونها لغة رسمية في تشاد وإريتريا وإسرائيل. وهي إحدى اللغات الرسمية الست في منظمة الأمم المتحدة.[7]
<callable_iterator object at 0x000000000BF29B38>
العربية لغة رسمية في كل دول الوطن العربي إضافة إلى كونها لغة رسمية في تشاد وإريتريا وإسرائيل.   !!وهي إحدى اللغات الرسمية الست في منظمة الأمم المتحدة.As you see it gives the match twice[7]

Comment: So that's what is to be expected right? Since you used `re.finditer` instead of `re.findall` `matches` is an iterator and not a list. Nevertheless the `TypeError` is gone so that should've solved your question, did it?

Comment: Nope. still repeats the pattern twice and the match throws a callable iterator object at certain position !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. As I mentioned the innermost `for` loop doesn't make any sense. It iterates over `row` which gives you an index and then the string. But you replace the loop variable `pattern` with `pattern=row[1].split('\n')` anyway. Also note that `start=1` doesn't skip the first element in the iterable but it starts the index at `1` (as opposed to `0`).

Comment: It would be easier if I could read Arabic, but as @a_guest said why aren't you using findall? Secondly Why are you using `^ Beginning String` and `$ End of String` directives and Why are you setting `test` into a tuple? If you save your text into a string regex can act on it. Not sure what I'm seeing but I did `re.findall('[\u0621-\u064A۰-۹0-9 ]+', text)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `test.txt` file is probably `utf-8` encoded. If the `test` string in your question is copied into `test.txt` using `utf-8` encoding and saved, then the following approach will give you the same results:

```
import re 

reg = r"^[\u0621-\u064A۰-۹0-9 ]+$"

with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    test = f_input.read()

# Looping over regex matches inside text
for match_num, match in enumerate(re.finditer(reg, test, re.MULTILINE), start=1):
    print(f"Match {match_num} was found at {match.start()}-{match.end()}: {match.group()}")
```

Namely, it gives the following output:

```
Match 1 was found at 0-63: هو الذي يصوركم في الأرحام كيف يشاء لا إله إلا هو العزيز الحكيم 
Match 2 was found at 64-124: ربنا إنك جامع الناس ليوم لا ريب فيه إن الله لا يخلف الميعاد 
Match 3 was found at 125-185: الصابرين والصادقين والقانتين والمنفقين والمستغفرين بالأسحار 
Match 4 was found at 186-197: 0123456789
```

Note: Python `f` strings could be used to simplify your print statements.